Linux: sed to replace string1 but only with grep string2
I should replace a certain string in a file but only in rows where appear another string, example:
This is myfile
Hello world
the world is mine

I would replace "world" only in the rows with hello using something like grep | xargs sed -i
but I do not know exacty how...
grep Hello myfile | sed -i 's/world/Italy/g myfile
the result I would obtain is:
Hello Italy
the world is mine

Thanks

You don't need grep.  sed has the ability to restrict commands to only those lines that match a pattern.  So:
sed  '/Hello/s/world/Italy/' < myfile

Output:
Hello Italy
the world is mine


This works better than (?<=Hello.)world, (see: https://regex101.com/r/wJOdwC/1), and the Code generator there produces non-working code...)

@Luuk: The problem with regex101.com is that it is not made sufficiently clear to users that the website does not generate regular expressions but Perl-compatible regular expressions (use grep option: -P).
